# Tips/Techniques on breaking down procedural programs into functions : Python

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, user-defined-functions

I'm new to python folks, please be gentle :)

I'm still brushing up on my python skills and want to get in the habit of creating functions with my programs. I was hoping to reach out to folks and ask for any tips/techniques on breaking down procedural programs into functions. I'm working on something now and I think I have a good direction in mind, but hoping to see if anyone has a rule of thumb or some advice they could offer.

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to Invitational Chess Tournament.1st Round Pairing below:")

def openlist:     
    myfile = open('CHESS.txt','r')
    players = []

def creatlist(players):
    for line in myfile:         
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        players.append(line)
        players.sort()

def findpairs(players):                             
    m= len(players)//2          
    for i in range(m):
        print (players[i],"&", players[i+m])

 myfile.close()  

main ()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's not clear if you are trying to define nested functions or using `myfile` as a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some (unsorted) advice:

- A function that doesn't return anything is called a "procedure"
- Make functions do one thing, and one thing only, without side-effects. Think giving the function something, modifying it and returning it. This way you can keep them short and it's easy to reuse them.
- Learn object-oriented programming (oop) it allows you to create "objects" out of things and makes programming much more intuitive for fresh programmers. As a really basic example, you can do things like: player.move(right);
- Related to the previous point, think about the scope of your functions. If a function is only used by it's enclosing class, make it private.
- Document your functions. At the start of every function, create a small comment that explains what it does (not how!) and maybe explain parameters. Not everybody likes this, but it's a must if you ever share your code in a library for example.

Concrete:

Staying with your design, `openlist` could be improved. It opens `myfile`, but it also creates an array `players[]`, but never returns either. You could remove the array declaration and add a return statement, but then you're left with a one line function that only initialises a variable. This is not very helpful, consider removing the function and just using `myfile = open...` directly.

`def creatlist(players)` is a more useful procedure, but you could make it more clear by defining it as `def createlistfromfile(file)` and making it return the initialised and filled array of players.

`def findpairs(players)` is fine, but try to make it return an array with pairs, instead of printing it directly. You might need to use it later on. Print the array with a different procedure.

Comment: thank you so much for all the resources and tips! i appreciate everyones help. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your function open list does nothing. It just creates 2 variables but never returns them. I would recommend you to read some basic python tutorials. They all cover functional programming. For example Wikibooks has some good articles: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming